# Solving the 'String or binary data would be truncated' error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
Declare @STAF_TO NVARCHAR(100)
```

I have the following query as part of a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
SELECT @SF_TO = TP.FRST_NAME + ' ' + TP.MDLE_NAME + ' ' + TP.LAST_NAME
FROM tbl_Sf TS 
INNER JOIN tbl_Pl TP ON (TS.POPL_PK = TP.POPL_PK)
WHERE TS.SF_PK = @ID
```

I know that `@ID` is equal to 140 (Type `INT`) based on a print statement that I inserted right before this. When I try to execute this query separately it works fine.

However, when I try to run it as part of the stored procedure I get the following error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure Proc_Name, Line 57
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

Line 57 being where the `SELECT` statement is of the query above. Anyone have any ideas why this could be happening?

EDIT: I tried changing `NVARCHAR(100)` to `NVARCHAR(200)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, still got the error. Also, the query works fine (with 100 characters) if I run it separately.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `@SF_TO`? This is the variable that is most likely being truncated.

Comment: Also what are the definitions of `FRST_NAME`, `MDLE_NAME` and `LAST_NAME`. I'd also suggest replacing your keyboard with one that doesn't miss vowels all the time. Any idea how much *harder* it is to type `FRST_NAME` than `FIRST_NAME`? You saved a character but you gained some gray hair.

Comment: @Love2Learn added declaration for `@SF_TO`

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree, but the table was around since long before I started working on it.

Comment: What does `if I run it separately` mean? Can you show what other parameters you have to your stored procedure other than `@ID`? And is `@ID` absolutely an `INT` parameter *and* an `INT` column in the table?

Comment: I think we need to see a bit more of the procedure. Normally for parameters and declared variables, you won't get that truncation error message, it'll just cut off the value, but you will get the error on an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to a table, of course.

Comment: @AaronBertrand `if I run seperately` means I open a prompt in SQL Server studio and just run the query. '@ID' is definitely an INT and is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Then there is something else you're not telling us (and I'm not saying that's intentional, but there has to be some information missing). Show us the *whole* procedure, how you're calling it, and the values of those three columns for `SF_PK = 140`.

Comment: What does teh stored proc do with the select statement, is it part of an insert?

Comment: Also the line of the sp that is indicated is not always where the actual error is. Look at the commands around it as well. You could be trying to troublshoot the wrong thing.

Comment: For those curious, an example of what happens with variables if they're too small: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e143/1 (No error, just shorter)

Comment: Your declaration does not match the variable in the select. Are they indeed the same variable? `@STAF_TO` versus `SF_TO`

Comment: @JasonWhisman yes, silent truncation. A reason [I tell people to always declare variable-length types with an explicit length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). We clearly need to see what is done with this variable next.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote because the reason for this is being hidden by logic not provided. The question as it is asked currently is inherently false. There have to be additional steps of factors in play that are unknown to us. I am particularly interested in the relationship between the two different variables in the explanation. It seems like `@STAF_TO` could potentially be an output variable while `@SF_TO` is a variable populated as an intermediary step and this is just being missed by the OP.

Answer (score 7):

It is almost certain that the definitions of your columns:

```
FRST_NAME
MDLE_NAME
LAST_NAME
```

Add up to more than 98 characters (+2 for the spaces).

I'd suggest declaring `@SF_TO` as something bigger than `NVARCHAR(100)` (but what, exactly, I don't know).

The error message is annoying to troubleshoot, for sure. It would be great if more specifics were included in the output. [Please vote/comment on this Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410).

Comment: +1, and voted. That error message is ridiculous!

Answer (score 2):

The concatenation statement is almost certainly resulting in records which are longer than the declared length of @SF_TO. You should increase the length of @SF_To.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the concatenation of:

```
TP.FRST_NAME + ' ' + TP.MDLE_NAME + ' ' + TP.LAST_NAME
```

is greater than `100` characters. Now, this may not be true on every single row, but it's true on the one you're selecting. If you ran this select statement:

```
SELECT TP.FRST_NAME + ' ' + TP.MDLE_NAME + ' ' + TP.LAST_NAME
FROM tbl_Sf TS 
INNER JOIN tbl_Pl TP ON (TS.POPL_PK = TP.POPL_PK)
WHERE LEN(TP.FRST_NAME + ' ' + TP.MDLE_NAME + ' ' + TP.LAST_NAME) > 100
```

you would be able to find the offending rows. Another approach is to simply make the `@STAF_TO` variable equal to the length of those three columns put together + 2. So, if the columns are all `50` characters long in their definitions, `@STAF_TO` should be `152`.

Comment: That query didn't return anything...

Comment: @ArtF, if that query didn't return anything then there is something more to this procedure we don't see. The error isn't happening there. Or this isn't the exact query that's in the procedure. I don't know what, but something is missing. Maybe you could post the entire procedure?